# Drag and Drop for React that supports IE8

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-8, drag-and-drop

Anybody knows Drag'n'Drop library for React that supports IE8?
Yes, i know that IE8 going to die but i need it.

I use es5shim, es6shim, html5shim etc. and tried some libs like [DnD](https://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/), [React-Draggable](https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable) and React-Drag but they don't support IE8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using React-Draggable on a project atm, I'm ignoring the nice wrapper and using DraggableCore which doesn't move any items for you, but gives you access to the raw numbers. Once you have those you could do some calculations and use absolute positioning instead of transform: translate.

You could even theoretically sniff for the browser version and use transform on modern browsers and position absolute for IE8.